# checking if user is opening root entry point of the IP address on esp8266 webserver

Tags: esp8266, wifi, web-server

I am trying to open load a webpage from ESP8266 that displays temperature and humidity of my room if I only type root URL:**`192.168.1.89`**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.89
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50
Accept-Language: en-us
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

to do that in my esp8266 sketch I am trying this logic:

```
bool readRequest(WiFiClient& client) {
  bool currentLineIsBlank = true;
  while (client.connected()) {
    if (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      if (c == "GET / HTTP/1.1"){
        Serial.println("Got root");
        client.println(handleRoot()); // where handle root contains web page
      }
      else{
        Serial.println("Did not got root.");
      }
      if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {

        return true;
      } else if (c == '\n') {
        currentLineIsBlank = true;
      } else if (c != '\r') {
        currentLineIsBlank = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

but the condition to check if it met `GET / HTTP/1.1` never validates.

Comment: `c` is a char. You can't compare a char to a string. And `c == "GET...` is not how you compare string in C, anyway.

Comment: Just use [a HTTP server library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/HelloServer/HelloServer.ino).

Comment: @gre_gor in a different project I am using `ESP8266WebServer ` but I want ed to give a try to `WiFiServer server(80);` while sticking with `ArduinoJson.h` library as well.

Comment: [This](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/) applies to networking as well as serial. Also [this](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/splitting-up-text-in-c/) may be of use to you, along with [this](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/).

Comment: @gre_gor I switched back to `ESP8266WebServer.h` however I cannot pass `ArduinoJson.h`'s jsonObject to `server.send(...)` https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/46961/27363